# How to use the normal probability table in reverse

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I'm just wondering if anyone could give me a bit of advice on this. This relates to CCEA's S1 exam questions.

$Z \sim \text{N}(0, 1)$

Let's say $\phi(z) = 0.5015$
Find z.

Here is an extract of the normal probability table that we're given in the exam.
[image: CCEA Normal probability table extract]

Now, our teacher said that, 'as far as he knows', if you cannot solve $\phi^{-1}$ for an exact value, you should always choose the value in the (ADD) column that gives less than the actual value.

So, using his advice, I would choose $z = 0.003$, since that would give $\phi(0.003) = 0.5012$ rather than choosing $z = 0.004$ which would give $\phi(0.004) = 0.5016$.

I just have concerns with this method, because he didn't seem totally sure that this is what you do, and 0.5016 is obviously more accurate than 0.5012 as they give differences of $10^{-4}$ and $3\times 10^{-4}$ respectively. This might be the correct method, but I just need to confirm it (exam is tomorrow!).

Thanks for any help!

Kelsey

P.S. I apologise if this has already been answered; I've looked on different forums, including this one, and I can't find anything that relates to this question.

Comment: People still use $z$ tables? That's what calculators are for...

Comment: @Shahar My calculator can do $\phi(z)$, but not $\phi^{-1}(z)$, so I'm not sure which value I should choose :(

Comment: The function is invNorm()... What calculator do you have?

Comment: @Shahar Casio fx-991ES PLUS. There are 4 functions in the 'Distribution' section: P(z) which calculates P(Z < z), Q(z) which calculates $|P(Z < z) - 0.5|$, and R(z) which calculates P(Z > z). It also has a 't' function, but I don't think this is the invNorm() function. It's on page 26/27 of this [manual](http://www.iaa.ncku.edu.tw/~smyang/%E9%82%B1%20%20%E8%9E%8D%20%E6%9B%B4%E6%94%B9/fx-570_991ES_PLUS_EN.pdf/) if you wouldn't mind having a look.

Comment: http://community.casiocalc.org/topic/4846-inverse-normal-distribution-in-fx-991es-plus/ Apparently you don't have it. However, you can write a program to solve it for you (such as the one linked in that thread).

Comment: I would use $0.004$, or interpolate and use $0.00375$. For "real" uses of the normal, fussing overly over accuracy is kind of pointless, since the assumptions that lead to using the normal have much greater built-in error than the error we are worrying about.

Comment: Depending on the number of places your Casio gives, you can use its function in reverse, plugging in numbers until you get close enough. One can give this root-finding method a fancy name, the Bisection Method.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
@AndréNicolas I think I'll use the most accurate value ($0.004$) as you said, because if people are finding it from calculators, then obviously they will be using the more accurate value :)

Comment: You are welcome. The CCEA may have a formal answer to your query. The criterion of choosing the lesser value does not make sense to me.